# XML Serialization not exporting list correctly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

I am trying to serialize an object to XML that should generate an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLFile xmlns="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <channels>
  <Ch01>
    <Name>Test Channel 01</Name>
    <Number>1</Number>
  </Ch01>
  <Ch02>
    <Company>Google</Company>
    <Founded>2015-10-23T13:04:04.2048888+01:00</Founded>
    <Founder>Some Guy</Founder>
  </Ch02>
  </channels>
</XMLFile>
```

Unfortunately the  tag is missing when I do the serialization, I have spent two hours trying to figure it out and I have had a colleague look and they also are stumped, below is a replica the code(not the real stuff from our project) it has the same issue.

Test code:

```
        XMLFile file = new XMLFile();
        file.channels.Add(new Ch01() {Name = "Test Channel 01", Number = 1});
        file.channels.Add(new Ch02() {Company = "Google", Founded = DateTime.Now, Founder = "Some Guy"});
        XMLSerialize.SerializeToXml(Application.StartupPath + "//test.xml", file);
```

XMLFile:

```
[Serializable]
public class XMLFile
{
    public XMLFile()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(Ch01))]
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(Ch02))]
    public List<channel> channels = new List<channel>(); 
}
```

channel:

```
[Serializable]
public class channel
{
    public channel()
    {

    }
}
```

Ch01:

```
[Serializable]
public class Ch01 : channel
{
    public Ch01()
    {

    }

    public string Name;
    public int Number;
}
```

Ch02:

```
[Serializable]
public class Ch02 : channel
{
    public Ch02()
    {

    }

    public string Company;
    public DateTime Founded;
    public string Founder;
}
```

XMLSerialize:

```
public static class XMLSerialize
{
    public static void SerializeToXml<T>(string file, T value)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://www.google.com");
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromXML<T>(string file)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://www.google.com");
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(file);
        T result;
        result = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLFile xmlns="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Ch01>
      <Name>Test Channel 01</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
   </Ch01>
   <Ch02>
      <Company>Google</Company>
      <Founded>2015-10-23T13:04:04.2048888+01:00</Founded>
      <Founder>Some Guy</Founder>
   </Ch02>
</XMLFile>
```

The project this is used in will generate a huge XML file so creating it manually via XmlDocument is not a good option.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say that "the tag is missing," are you referring to the XML declaration at the top ("<?xml version=...")? You've shown us your expected output - it might help to see your actual output.

Comment: Sorry forgot about that. I have added the real output, the <channels> tag is missing

Comment: Shouldn't `[XmlArray("channels")]` do this for you?

Comment: You would expect [XmlArray] to work, but then throws the error 'There was an error reflecting type' because it no longer knows what to do with Ch01/Ch02 (even though i didn't remove them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can use XmlArray but you need to specify the types of derived classes as well as shown below:

```
public class XMLFile
{
    public XMLFile()
    {

    }

    [XmlArray("channels")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Ch01), ElementName = "Ch01")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Ch02), ElementName = "Ch02")]
    public List<channel> channels = new List<channel>();
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know [XmlArrayItem] exisited! This appears to work so thank you :)